# XML -parsing metadata properties with DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

Need someones help in parsing this example below.  I need to get, for example, the value of the "Exchange" property .
Much appreciated.  Al.

XML content,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<History>
   <Metadata>
      <MetadataType FormalName="Keywords" />
      <Property FormalName="CategoryKeywords" Value="Photo/Multimedia" />
      <Property FormalName="CountryKeywords" Value="UK" />
      <Property FormalName="RegKeywrd" Value="Europe" />
   </Metadata>
   <Metadata>
      <MetadataType FormalName="Securities Id" />
      <Property FormalName="Ticker Symbol" Value="ABC" />
      <Property FormalName="Exchange" Value="London" />
   </Metadata>
</History>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <History>
        <Metadata>
           <MetadataType FormalName="Keywords"/>
           <Property FormalName="CategoryKeywords" Value="Photo/Multimedia"/>                     
           <Property FormalName="CountryKeywords" Value="UK"/>
           <Property FormalName="RegKeywrd" Value="Europe"/>
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
           <MetadataType FormalName="Securities Id"/>
           <Property FormalName="Ticker Symbol" Value="ABC"/>
           <Property FormalName="Exchange" Value="London"/>
        </Metadata>        
    </History>

Answer (score 0):

try with following solution,

```
public class DomParser {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         File inputFile = new File("Test.xml");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document document = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
         document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Property");

         for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(temp);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element element = (Element) node;
               System.out.println("Property (FormalName) : " + element.getAttribute("FormalName") + 
                                  ", Value : " + element.getAttribute("Value"));
            }
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

output,

```
Property (FormalName) : CategoryKeywords, Value : Photo/Multimedia
Property (FormalName) : CountryKeywords, Value : UK
Property (FormalName) : RegKeywrd, Value : Europe
Property (FormalName) : Ticker Symbol, Value : ABC
Property (FormalName) : Exchange, Value : London
```